# ipTables blocking memcached

Tags: ubuntu, memcached, iptables

I have one server running memcached and another server that should be able to connect to the memcached server.

memcached is set up to listen to 0.0.0.0:5666

This allows for anyone to connect to it so i want to block the port 5666 for everyone except the other server. I thought this would do it:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5666 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 79.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT
```

But it did not, now i can not connect at all from the other server, before it worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iptables rules are evaluated in the order that they're given.  Just switch the order of those two lines.

Answer (score 2):

You need the ACCEPT condition before before the REJECT condition. By putting the REJECT first it rejects your valid IP and then stops and your second rule is never seen.